# How to use youtube dl?

Tags: php, windows, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-dl

How to use youtube dl on Windows XP for downloading youtube videos.Have any commands ?I want to integrate this tool with PHP.Please help..

Answer (score 5):

After downloading youtube-dl, just do the following:

```
chmod 777 youtube-dl

./youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whatever
```

Comment: from where to download youtube dl for windows?

Comment: @sreerajvr Isn't [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/) a Python script? If so, then it runs on any OS with Python installed. (or are we talking about two different things?)

Comment: youtube-dl gets installed into /usr/bin by default on Linux debian, fyi.  You'll have to cd to there first before your chmod command above.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the current Youtube API doesn't allow you to download videos. I would recommend something like:

http://www.swfkits.com/swf-to-video-sdk/

I used this recently to automatically convert SWF to MP4, then store that. My application then uploading this to youtube all automatically though.

It is not cheap for the full version, around £900. However it is the only CLI I found that does this (meaning you can use PHP shell_exec to run it).

May I also add that you should never download youtube videos that aren't your own without express consent.

[EDIT] - Sorry, I didn't release you already had a youtube downloader script (until Gaurav Gupta answered below - use his answer) - maybe make this clearer in the question? The tags only mention the Youtube API and the reference to the actual script is vague and confusing.

Comment: You're right, YouTube officially does not allow downloading videos. But youtube-dl manages a workaround!